# Attaching a callback before validation of form

Tags: jquery, validation

I am using jquery form validation plugin 
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

How can I set a callback which will be get called before calling it's validation function ?
I want to trim the values and some pre-validation.

Comment: Callback before actual validation? or before submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

addMethod() lets you create own validation method instead of using predfined ones. Within method do the processing necessary.

For example for trimming you could trim the value, and replace it in field...and test against the trimmmed value. Otherwise using change event handlers on fields would likely help also

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

Answer (score 0):

Putting @charlietfl's answer into practice, this is what I've done (in case it's useful to anyone):

```
$.validator.addMethod('trim',
  function(value, element, param) {
    $(element).val($.trim(value));
    return true;
  }
);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my_form').validate({
    rules: {
      name: {
        trim: true,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        trim: true,
        email: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The first rule trims the value, then you can add additional rules like `required` or `email`.